# Javascript required attribute not working with e.preventDefault

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with inputs that have the required attribute.However, I dont want the form to be submitted normally, but it uses ajax.Thus, I set the form action to `javascript:void(0)` .But doing so, renders the `required` attribute useless.It doesn't work

How can I fix that?

This is my form

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)"> <input name="email" required> </form>`
```

Comment: Also post the ajax/jquery code snippet

Comment: Provide ajax code and also complete code for form, does the form not have a submit button?

Comment: So onsubmit cancel it, unclear why you are using action....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So use the submit handler on the form and cancel the default action.

```js
document.querySelector("#myForm").addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // do you ajax submission here
  console.log('submitted')
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <label for="email">email:</label> <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing the submit yourself you can check the validity of the form with

```
if (form.checkValidity()) {
  // submit via XHR etc...
} else {
  // the form is not valid
}
```

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation)

Answer (score 0):

do it like this may help you

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <input name="email" required>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script>
  document.myForm.onsubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
</script>
```